# Convert an image into matrix of specific dimensions?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, image-processing, matrix

Is it possible to convert the image into an array of specific dimensions in python?

I have a group of images of different sizes. And I need them all to be exactly in a 50 X 50 matrix.

Is it possible to read an image via matplotlib preferably and then convert that array into a 50 X 50 array?

If it's possible, then how can I do it?

Comment: Did you have a look at library `PIL.Image`? It's litterally their first tutorial here https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html - using `thumbnail(50, 50)` should help.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) library is what you want.

```
from PIL import Image
image_paths = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]
arrays = list()

for image_path in image_paths:
    img = Image.open(image_path)
    img.thumbnail(size=(50, 50))
    img_as_array = np.array(img)
    arrays.append(img_as_array)
```

Now `arrays` contains your images resized to (50, 50) as arrays!